# Required request part is not present - Springboot 2.2.1

Tags: spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I am facing the same problem as [Springboot Required request part 'file' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748961/springboot-required-request-part-file-is-not-present/74110062#74110062)
and the solutions provided here have not worked. Spring boot version v2.2.1

[Postman Req Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU3je.png)

spring.http.multipart.enabled=true

Anything else I can do?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/executescript", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE) 
public @ResponseBody String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("File") MultipartFile file)
```

Comment: Hard to say anything useful without knowing how you'r sending the data

Comment: updated the post to add Postman req

Comment: you should change @RequestParam("file")  instead of "File"

Comment: @debugmode no luck, same error even with @RequestParam("file")

Comment: add annotation "@RequestPart" instead of "@RequestParam"

Comment: @debugmode same error. An update, this works perfectly fine on a colleague's Windows 10 machine but not in my Windows 11 machine. Same jdk version.

Comment: unfortunately without error we can't help you. share your stack trace that you face to problem