# Unable to test controller for CSV upload java spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a working controller for uploading csv's in a post request. Status 200 in postman, status 400 while testing. I'm struggling to see what the problem is.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/csv")
public class CsvController {
    final CsvService csvService;

    public CsvController(CsvService csvService) {
        this.csvService = csvService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file) {
        if(CsvHelper.hasCSVFormat(file)) {
            Response response = csvService.save(file);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
        }

        Response response = new Response().setStatus(400).setMessage("Please upload a CSV file");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
    }
}
```

CsvHelper Util:

```
public class CsvHelper {
    public static String TYPE = "text/csv";

    public static boolean hasCSVFormat(MultipartFile file) {
        return TYPE.equals(file.getContentType());
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = CsvController.class)
public class TestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CsvService csvService;

    @Test
    void status200WhenUploadingCSV() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(
                "multipartFile",
                "template.csv",
                "text/csv",
                new ClassPathResource("template.csv").getInputStream());

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/csv/upload")
                .file(mockMultipartFile))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
}}
```

When the test fails I can see this Resolved Exception:
Type = org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException

Answer (score 0):

this error is because of the file size you are uploading. It can be fixed by setting max upload size.

add this to your main class.

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000L);
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

Comment: Please revert back if there is any furthur issue.

Comment: I already added this to my applications.property

`spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB`

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs sometimes when the `@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file` the `file` is being empty or it is not receiving any attribute.
You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936372/upload-file-springboot-required-request-part-file-is-not-present/43952169).
Maybe it can solve your problem.
Or you can specify your file size in the `application.properties` file as:

```
    spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
    spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=11MB
```