# Spring Boot doesn't recognize multipart form-data element when filename is missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, http-headers

I have this code:

```
@PostMapping("foobar")
public ResponseEntity<SaveLogsResult> foobar(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile log, @RequestPart("env") MultipartFile json){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(fooService.saveFooBar(log, json, UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
}
```

Two applications send formally correct data to this endpoint, one fails miserably and receives an http status 400.

I set `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` and can see (among other lines) this:

```
Required request part 'env' is not present
Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'env' is not present]
Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

To further diagnose this I compared a working (left) and a non-working (right) request. The only different is the mising `filename`:

[image]

As far as I understand the [RFC for Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#as_a_header_for_a_multipart_body) leaving out the `filename` is perfectly valid:

> Is followed by a string containing the original name of the file
> transmitted. The *filename is always optional* and must not be used
> blindly by the application: path information should be stripped, and
> conversion to the server file system rules should be done. This
> parameter provides mostly indicative information. When used in
> combination with Content-Disposition: attachment, it is used as the
> default filename for an eventual "Save As" dialog presented to the
> user.

Is this an error inside Spring ? I use Spring Boot 2.6.2
Unfortunately I can't change the non-working component for a quick test because it is a bought component that doesn't receive bugfixes very often.
I think that my problem is different from that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936372/upload-file-springboot-required-request-part-file-is-not-present) because the failure only happens in a specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to provide the filename. see this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27245)

> This [*The situation in which filename is not present*] can lead to inconsistencies, e.g. you would get it with
> MultipartFile but not with collection or array of MultipartFile, and
> one can make the opposite argument that it should be rejected.
>
> Why does it matter to have it injected as MultipartFile if it doesn't
> even have a filename? You could also inject it as InputStream or any
> other type supported by a registered HttpMessageConverter.