# HttpServletRequest.getParts() returns empty parts list

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I have a Spring-Boot 2.7.1 app.
I need to forward Multipart-Request to Apache JaxRS legacy implementation. Therefore I need to call a method which receives
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody as parameter.

In Spring mvc I call in my Post handler:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ....;
Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
```

My intention is to create an MultipartBody object with a list of org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment. So far it works in normal cases.
But there is an edge case when I am requesting like this:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8083/mysServlet
```

with this headers

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=B57B89AB8EDB2ECBBB69CBC66BD4C7880
```

and this body:

```
--B57B89AB8EDB2ECBBB69CBC66BD4C7880
Content-Length: 2
X-compId: data



--B57B89AB8EDB2ECBBB69CBC66BD4C7880--
```

In this case getParts() returns 0 instead of 1.

I found these similar issue: [Spring Boot doesn't recognize multipart form-data element when filename is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984624/spring-boot-doesnt-recognize-multipart-form-data-element-when-filename-is-missi)

RFC2183 :

> It specifies the "Content-Disposition" header field, which is optional and valid for any MIME entity ("message" or "body part").

RFC2388 chapter 3:

> "multipart/form-data" contains a series of parts. Each part is
> expected to contain a content-disposition header [RFC 2183] where the
> disposition type is "form-data", and where the disposition contains
> an (additional) parameter of "name", where the value of that
> parameter is the original field name in the form. For example, a part
> might contain a header:

```
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"
```

Is the Content-Disposition header according RFC inside parts required?

Here the header is explained: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

The tomcat implementation, used by spring, requires such an header.

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem()

Therefore it seems, I need to parse the body by my self. Maybe be using apache MultipartStream: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/MultipartStream.html

Which lib I could use to parse the multipart formdata, so that I can fulfill my task?

Answer (score 0):

I have to comply an interface in order to get our product get certified. Therefore I solved it by an own custom dispatcher servlet and an partly own implemented multipart parsing implementation based on apache MultipartStream. This works and I could comply all tests. (The interface is old and obviously doesn't comply to all current standards)