# Unable to upload file or Image from Postman to Java API

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to write an API where I am sending Image from postman but I am getting following error.
Can you please help me on this ?

**API ::**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadImageAndData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void initiateReturns(@RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile file){

       // remaining code

    }
```

**Postman Request ::**

[image]

Comment: Your code snippet and Postman screenshot looks good to me. There might be some configuration in your project that interferes with it. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936372/upload-file-springboot-required-request-part-file-is-not-present

Comment: can you use content-type as "multipart/form-data" in your request mapping & see if it works?

Comment: @Ashish .I have tried adding mentioned content-type , but unfortunately same error still persists

Comment: What is the size of the file you want to upload?

Comment: @Nemanja ...I am uploading file of 300 KB

Comment: Are you using  spring boot?

Comment: change `@RequestParam("file")` to `@RequestBody("file")` in the controller method

Answer (score 0):

Have you create filter, resolver, and register it in fileUploadUrlFilterMappings? It's located in spring-filter-config.xml

```
    <!-- Filter -->
    <bean id="importCSVMultipartFilter" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter">
        <property name="multipartResolverBeanName" value="importCSVMultipartResolver"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- resolver -->
    <bean id="importCSVMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('import.csv.max.upload.size.bytes')}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- URL filter mapping -->
    <alias name="defaultFileUploadUrlFilterMappings" alias="fileUploadUrlFilterMappings" />
    <util:map id="defaultFileUploadUrlFilterMappings" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter">
        <entry key="/import/csv/*" value-ref="importCSVMultipartFilter"/>
    </util:map>
```